# UIButton border padding

Tags: objective-c, uikit

This looks like an easy enough question, but I can't seem to find a solution online. I use an `UIButton`'s layer to make a border for it. And the border shows. The problem is that the paddings (top/right/bottom/left, obviously this term comes from the CSS world) of the border are too small, and I want to increase them. How do I do that?

Here is my code:

```
myButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
myButton.layer.borderWidth = 2;
myButton.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

And the button looks like above.
[image: Button border with tight padding]

Comment: @lgc_ustc: could you please add a screen shot for the issue button

Comment: tried increasing the borderwidth?

Comment: Yes, tried increasing borderwidth. It just increased the width rather than padding (space between button content and button border).

Answer (score 7):

Try changing the `contentEdgeInsets`. These are the outer-most margins for the rectangle surrounding all of the button’s content.

For example: `myButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5,5,5,5);`

Answer (score 2):

Use `titleEdgeInsets` Property of `UIButton`

```
        myButton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(5, 5, 5, 5);
```

Adjust the insets as required! You can get more details about `titleEdgeInsets` from [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIButton/titleEdgeInsets)

Comment: No. Tried that, and did not seem to change anything visually.

Comment: UIEdgeInsetsMake is the way to do it as Asif said (I up-voted).  However, depending on your font, you might need to make the the insets a lot bigger, like 17 if your font size is 15 as I found out.   You can play with the edgeInsets with IB in the Attributes Inspector.  You'll see there's a dashed box around your UIButtton text and when you play with the 4 insets the box moves around your text.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can reduce the button font size like,

```
myButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
```

or just change the frame size of button in storyboard or programatically[image]

Comment: Have you tried your solution? It doesn't work for me. When you decrease font size, the border shrinks too.

Comment: Hmm, did you make changes in other parts of the code? Because I can't make your code to work (when I decreased font size, the border shrank too).

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 15, if you use UIButtonConfiguration, It will be :

```
button.configuration.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 2, left: 4, bottom: 2, right: 4)
```

for older version:

```
button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 2, left: 4, bottom: 2, right: 4)
```